# Configuring ZenOSS to monitor CPU load

Tags: windows-xp, cpu-usage, wmi, zenoss

I'm trying test out monitoring tools for a network at work with a coworker but neither of us have ever used an sort of monitoring tools before. Currently we are experimenting with ZenOSS and having some difficulties. We want to populate our CPU load graphs because that is one of the primary feature we are looking for in our monitoring tools but we have been unable to populate the graphs with data.

So far we have installed the wmipreformance, sqldatasource, wmidatasource, snmpperformance(simple) zenpacks and the machine we are trying to monitor is running Windows XP.

We have tried to model the device and everything seems to run and we've tride to add data points to graphs but the only options we recieve for graphs are CPU and Memory.

We are able to monitor services, ZenOSS recognizes the make and model of the processor, RAM, and Harddrive and is even giving us metrics on available storage but again, we are looking for performance metrics such as CPU load and Memory utilization.

I realize I probably didn't provide a lot of information but that is because we don't have a very good idea of what we are doing and can't find instruction either on the ZenOSS homepage or forums to monitor CPU load. If someone could give us step by step instruction on how to set up CPU load monitoring that would probably be more beneficial to us than a diagnostic of our current setup, but regardless, if I left any important information out and you need it to answer the question, please let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The default Windows device class in ZenOSS has two requirements. First, enable SNMP and make sure that you've set the community strings correctly. Second, install the free SNMP informant module on the server you're trying to monitor, which Zenoss uses to collect more reliable statistics via SNMP.

Now, you also mentioned you installed the WMI performance zenpack, which will require you to move the device into a device configured for WMI modeling and performance collection.

You shold not have have to be defining datapoints or graphs at this stage, the built-in templates should be providing these for you.

This link may help you

http://binarynature.blogspot.com/2011/06/configure-windows-device-for-zenoss.html